# Trouble loading CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I have an issue that is somewhat similar to this:

[Publish Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124520/publish-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cefsharp-core-dll)

I am developing a plugin for a larger .NET desktop application written in C#. The larger / parent application includes an older version of Chromium (about 2 years old) and the purpose of my plugin is to load and use the latest version of Chromium. The parent app, my plugin, and CefSharp all target x86.

The folder structure looks sort of like this:

```
C:\...\ParentApp\ParentApp.exe
C:\...\ParentApp\CefSharp.dll (version 71)
C:\...\ParentApp\CefSharp.Core.dll (v71)
C:\...\ParentApp\CefSharp.WinForms.dll (v71)
C:\...\ParentApp\...etc... (v71)

C:\...\ParentApp\plugins\MyPlugin\MyPlugin.dll (references and loads version 83.4.20)
C:\...\ParentApp\plugins\MyPlugin\CefSharp.dll (v83)
C:\...\ParentApp\plugins\MyPlugin\CefSharp.Core.dll (v83)
C:\...\ParentApp\plugins\MyPlugin\CefSharp.WinForms.dll (v83)
C:\...\ParentApp\plugins\MyPlugin\...etc... (v83)
```

The parent app rarely uses Chromium, so my plugin actually runs first and when it loads, it just runs the basic initialization:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

I can see with Process Monitor (Procmon) that it loads up all the files from the plugin's location (which is v83) first, although it does see and check the v71 files, too.

After the "new CefSettings()" line, I also injected a dump of the current assemblies with:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

...and I could see that it indeed had loaded up the 3 main assemblies (CefSharp.Core, CefSharp.WinForms, and CefSharp) with version 83.4.20.0, which is the correct version.

But as soon as I hit Cef.Initialize(settings), it triggers exceptions:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=83.4.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at CefSharp.Internals.CefSharpApp.OnBeforeChildProcessLaunch(CefSharpApp* , scoped_refptr<CefCommandLine>* commandLine)

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=83.4.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at CefSharp.Internals.CefSharpApp.OnContextInitialized(CefSharpApp* )
```

I've tried a variety of things, including setting up everything in a separate appdomain, but that ran into other issues.

Anyone have any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/  Make sure you do a clean build.  You may have some intermediate object files that are not getting rebuilt.  The issue could either be with main project or any of you child projects.

Comment: I tried using cefsharp yesterday for the first time in an existing x86 project and got exact the same problem. I'm not using a deployed build, debugging it in Visual Studio is enough to get this error.

Comment: @Sander it's a very generic error message and it's unlikely your problem relates to this one in any way. I'd suggest you ask your own question.

Comment: @jhilgeman Is your plugin loaded into the default app domain?

Comment: @amaitland - yes it is all loaded into the default app domain.

Comment: The separate appdomain was just an idea I tried and rolled back.

Comment: CefSharp doesn't work if loaded in the non default appdomain, this is a limitation of vc++. I've never attempted what you are trying so not sure it's actually possible. One reason for the error you are seeing is that CefSharp.Core.dll cannot find libcef.dll, does procmon give any hints? Is it attempting to load any of the files listed at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29

Comment: @amaitland - Yes, it loads almost all of those files mentioned, and it loads them from the plugin directory. When I get the exception, the end of procmon indicates it was successfully reading libcef.dll from my plugin folder.

Comment: What happens if you manually call Assembly.Load for CefSharp.dll

Comment: Are you 100% sure the parent application isn't loading your plugin into a new appdomain?

Comment: If you are running in the default appdomain then it sounds like the host application has pre loaded an older version of CefSharp.dll

Comment: @amaitland - I dumped a list of appdomains and confirmed that there is only one app domain at the moment. I did try the Assembly.Load early on, but maybe I need to separate out some things. I'll comment a bit later.

Comment: @amaitland - Procmon doesn't show an older version of CefSharp being pre-loaded. My guess is that somehow CefSharp may be trying to load some dependency from the default appdomain's base directory (where the old version is), and I'm just not seeing it among the volume of other filesystem calls.

Comment: If you can hook https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.6.2 early enough you should be able to control which assembly is loaded. Option 2 in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714 has an example if that doesn't work then I'm out of ideas.